Get Values from Multiple Checkboxes and pass it to server side based on Question Number
I'm new to PHP and would love to ask about how to get multiple values on checkbox based on the question number. I provide a screenshot of a program that i working to.

This is the PHP generating HTML :-
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php foreach ($dua as $d) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d['nama_soal'] ?></td>
      <td><img style="border-radius: 5px; width: 375px; height: auto;" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/dashboard/images/soalcfit/subtest2/' . $d['img_soal'] . '.jpg'); ?>" alt=""></td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkoption<?php echo $d['id'] ?>" name="jsub2[]" value="A"> A
        &nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkoption<?php echo $d['id'] ?>" name="jsub2[]]" value="B"> B
        &nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkoption<?php echo $d['id'] ?>" name="jsub2[]" value="C"> C
        &nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkoption<?php echo $d['id'] ?>" name="jsub2[]" value="D"> D
        &nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkoption<?php echo $d['id'] ?>" name="jsub2[]" value="E"> E
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

This is the Controller for submitting the post :-
public function c2_proses() {
    if ($this->input->post()) {
        //input per subtest
        $jsub2 = $this->input->post('jsub2');

        //untuk foreach soal
        $soal2 = $this->CfitModel->getDataAllSoalSubDua();
        
        //variabel id user
        $id_user = $_SESSION['user_id'];

        //foreach kombinasi sub-1
        foreach($soal2 as $key => $s2)
        {
            $this->CfitModel->inputValue($id_user, $s2['id'], $jsub2[$key]);
        }

        redirect('ujian/csub2');
    }
}

This is the Model :-
public function inputValue($id_user, $id_soal, $jawaban) {
    return $this->db->insert('cfit_hasil', array('id_user' => $id_user, 'id_soal' => $id_soal, 'jawaban' => $jawaban));
}

For example when  i choose A,B from Question number one, and C, D for Question number two, but the output is like this :-

A
B
C
D

I need my output on the database like :-

AB
CD, etc.


Use the question ID as an additional array level - name="jsub2[xy][]" - xy would be the question ID.

but in image you have selected  A,B options in both questions.

@KUMAR yeah, it's just for example. It fixed now.
